# "The page does not redirect correctly" laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to make a album for a homework assignment. However, I am stuck with an error. I am trying to use validation but it is not working.

I am using a step by step youtube toturial to help me make this album. However, this specific problem is not explained. I have also read the laravel websites section concerning validation. I did not really get any answers there either. Finally, I looked up some similar questions on StackOverflow, however, I did not get the answers I desired.

I am getting the following error: "The page does not redirect correctly"

My albumController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class albumController extends Controller
{
    public function albums(){
        return view("albums");
    }

    public function create(){
        return view("create");
    }
/* You have to work on the request later. Make sure that when someone logs in, he returns 123 */
    public function store(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'naam' => 'required',
            'cover_image' => 'image|max:1999'
        ]);
    }
}
```

My albums.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<h1><b>Ons album</b></h1>
<form method="post" action="/store">
@csrf
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Naam van Album</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" placeholder="Naam" name="naam">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleTextarea">Omschrijving</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3" name="omschrijving"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Zoek uw bestand</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp" name="cover_image">
    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Selecteer uw bestand</small>
  </div>


  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
@endsection
```

My web.php:

```
Route::GET('/index',('PageController@index'));

Auth::routes();
//Zorg ervoor dat auth verplicht is
Route::get('/albums', 'albumController@albums')->name('albums')->middleware('auth');/*Zorgt ervoor dat je ingelogt moet zijn om naar albums te kunnen gaan*/

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/create', 'albumController@create')->name('create');

Route::post('/store', 'albumController@store');

Route::get('/store', 'albumController@store');
```

Hopefully I have provided you with enough information to help me find an answer.

Greetings,

Parsa_237

Comment: You didn't provide the most important part of the question: the question

Comment: Please see the edit, I have written down the error I want to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The page does not redirect correctly

You have two routes with different methods going to the same controller function

```php
// This one is okay
Route::post('/store', 'albumController@store');

// This one is the problem, delete it
Route::get('/store', 'albumController@store');
```

That's because the POST request is submitted but nothing is returned

Whether the validation passes or fail, nothing happens

Also the `image` validation rule doesn't have a `max` attribute, move that to the string `naam` instead

do something with the validated data or just return a response

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'naam' => 'required|max:1999',
        'cover_image' => 'image'
    ]);
    // Do something with the validated data
    return response()->json(['status' => 123]);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, however. I am still getting the same error: "The page does not redirect correctly"

Comment: So i should upload a image into the database to get my response?

Comment: No you don't have to unless you want to or asked to, the problem might be in your routes and I don't know where you want to redirect, edit your question and add `routes/web.php` file

Comment: I have added it

Comment: Yes but one of them is a GET and another one a POST. If I delete the GET then the GET method will not be supported for that route. If I delete the POST then I will get the same error as I have now.

Comment: Yes but the GET method **should not** be supported, and even if you want to support it, it can't link to the same function, the code can't tell head from tail this way